# Not able to post the parameters from one file to another with the file which should come before posted file

Tags: php, html

I am new to developing and I dont no much about html and php. I have a check box with different texts, once I select and submit, it should post to file tree.php. But tree.php should print within 2nd frame. So I have different frames in frame.php. I want the check box output as a input to tree.php. I want to print different frames before tree.php. How can be achieved? Thanks in advance.

```
function user_access() {
    $projectidarr=array();

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
        if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {

            // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.

            foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected)
            {
                $projectidarr[]=$selected;
                echo "<p>".$selected ."</p>";
            }
        }

        for($i=0; $i<count($projectidarr); $i++)
        {
            echo $projectidarr[$i];
        }
    }
    return $projectidarr;
}
?>

<frameset rows="13%,87%,*%">
<frame src="header.php" scrolling=no >
    <frameset cols="20%,80%,*%" >
    <frame src="Tree.php" name="tree" >
            <frameset rows="40%,60%,*%">
                <frame src="http://localhost/JqueryAjax/chart4.php" name="table" scrolling=yes >
                <frame src="Tables\project_table.php" name="graph" scrolling=no >  
            </frameset> 
    </frameset>
</frameset>

</html>
```

Comment: frame src="Tree.php" is closed with </frameset> tag generally using frames is veeeery obsolete

Comment: the title itself gave me headache, still searching for the meaning.. for your problem i see 2 ways: communication between frames with Javascript (assuming they come from same domain. No reload, does not trigger another PHP execution, only interacts with the resulting HTML/JS) or reload the frame and pass the parameter for example as a GET variable through the URL (triggers the frame content reload)

Comment: before posting the output to another file, I want to execute Frame.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to redesign whole approach. For the beginning you can explore php include function http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php
Then your sample index.php can look like this:

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit']) {
  include "processForm.php";
}

include "header.php";
switch($url) {
  case "":     include "home.php"; break;
  case "form": include "form.php"; break;
  default:     include "404.php";
}
include "footer.php";
?>
```

This is very simplified code written only as example. It is a good habbit to use some $ROOT variable/constant, which is used in every include, to determine the correct paths. You should process forms before any HTML output to keep the possibility to set HTTP headers before output

Comment: can't I have any other options?

Comment: millions of options ;) You should have one main script which decides what to run in every state and controls all app logic and not rely on frames. frames can inter-communicate only by javascript